# Allow for children in react element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am making a react app using expo and I want to allow children in my TopicSection element. I followed [this guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) for allowing children in JSX elements and wrote the below code. I have tried using this.props.children but either way it gives me "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.children')"

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import { RectButton, ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default function TopicsScreen() {
  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container} contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
      <TopicSection
        icon="ios-chatboxes"
        text="Introduction">
          <Text>This is where I want to put elements</Text>
      </TopicSection>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
function TopicSection({icon, text, props}) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.TopicSection}>
      <View style={styles.TopicSectionContainer && {flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Ionicons name={icon} size={32} color="rgba(0,0,0,0.35)" />
        <Text style={styles.TopicSectionText}>{" " + text}</Text>
      </View>
        {props.children}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: You’re using function components. Use children as a normal prop.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm really new to react, how would I do that?

Comment: I’d recommend reading the tutorial first https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

You’re destructuring the `props` object in TopicSection, so by doing `({icon, text, props})`, you’re implying there is a prop called `props`, which there isn’t.

You either need to destructure out `children` and use it directly, or do `...props`, which assigns all the remaining, unspecified props to `props`.